# Node module for OAuth2 Access Token generation?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am working on Node.js in which I am using **superagent** to call oauth token generation request and I am manually parsing a response from which I am extracting access_token, refresh_token, token_type, expires_in,etc.

below is the snippet for oauth token generation via superagent call

```
superagent
    .post('https://myapi.com/oauth_token.do')
    .proxy(proxy)
    .type('form')
    .send({grant_type: 'password' })
    .send({client_id: 'client-id-value' })
    .send({client_secret: 'client-secreat-value' })
    .send({username: 'user' })
    .send({password: 'pass' })
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .end(function(err, res){
    if (err || !res.ok) {           
        // error handling..
    } else {
        // response parsing..
    });
```

I am looking for the node.js module which will take care of oauth token generation. Is there any node js module for the same ?
If possible could you please share the sample as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For token generation you can try either of following:

[rand-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rand-token) or [node-hat](https://github.com/substack/node-hat)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to generate token via REST API.

Answer (score 0):

auth0 provides good libraries.  In node, I use `jsonwebtoken`.  If you scroll down the https://jwt.io/ page, they list a ton of libraries and features.

Here is what signing a JWT looks like with their library.

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

// setup...

const token = jwt.sign(oPayload, bufferPrivateKey, 
  { algorithm: 'ES256',
    issuer: 'ME-MYSELF-I',
    expiresIn: '30 days'
  });
```